# How do I track multiple Google Optimize experiments in Google AMP?

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html, google-optimize

The [`amp-experiment` docs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-experiment#configuration) demonstrate tracking multiple experiments in AMP. However, how do I configure the `amp-analytics` properly?

In the [reporting](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-experiment/#reporting) section of the docs, it mentions a `VARIANTS` placeholder that will be replaced with a serialized list of experiment and variant names. [This answer](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Optimize-Experiment/Simultaneous-A-B-testing-on-the-same-page/td-p/1109857#.W3WA-Fa0p18.link) from the Google Optimize team seems to indicate that it could be added to requests in `<amp-analytics>` like so:

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "vars": {
        "account": "..."
      },
      "requests": {
        "experiment": "${pageview}&exp=VARIANTS"
      },
      "triggers": {
        "pageview": {
          "on": "visible",
          "request": "experiment"
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

When I try this, though, Google Optimize doesn't register any visits. It seems to require that the `experiment` request include `xid`/`xvar` (for experiment ID/variant) instead:

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      ...
      "requests": {
        "experiment": "${pageview}&xid=${xid}&xvar=${xvar}"  <-- modified
      },
      "triggers": {
        "pageview": {
          "on": "visible",
          "request": "experiment",
          "vars": {                                          <-- added
            "xid": "skdjEjia23_1ksjd",                       <-- 
            "xvar": "VARIANT(my-experiment-name)"            <-- 
          }                                                  <-- 
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

This works fine, but then I can only run one experiment at a time, since the `xid`/`xvar` are hard-coded to a specific experiment.

Any ideas how I can run multiple experiments?

Comment: Can you please post the resulting request URL for `"experiment": "${pageview}&exp=VARIANTS"` (e.g. from the network tab in Chrome DevTools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. I got an answer from the Google Optimize team in the [Google Optimize forum](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Optimize-Experiment/Simultaneous-A-B-testing-on-the-same-page/td-p/1109857#.W3rWxCRk0mU.link).

The `VARIANTS` variable gets replaced with serialized experiment *names* and variants, but what Google Analytics apparently needs is experiment *IDs* and variants. Thus, the correct solution was to configure `<amp-analytics>` this way:

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "vars": {
        "account": "..."
      },
      "requests": {
        "experiment": "${pageview}&exp=a1b2c3.VARIANT(my-first-experiment)!d4e5f6.VARIANT(my-second-experiment)"
      },
      "triggers": {
        "pageview": {
          "on": "visible",
          "request": "experiment",
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Note that `a1b2c3` and `d4e5f6` are the experiment IDs, not the names. The `.VARIANT(...)` portions following them indicate the index of the variant selected for those experiments. No idea why the IDs are used in the first place and the names in the `VARIANT()` callbacks ‍♂️